# Limit for URL length for "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler"?

Tags: java, windows, url

I have a long URL with tons of parameters that I want to open in the default browser from Java on a Windows system using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "+url)
```

For short URLs like "http://www.google.com" this works fine. But for long URLs (say, 2000 characters), this simply does absolutely nothing at all: no exception or anything of the sort, it is simply ignored.

Is there a character limit a) for a Runtime.exec command or b) for the rundll32 url.dll command? If so, what is the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be running up against [this (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190902193246/https://boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) operating system/browser specific maximum URL length problem:

For "rundll32 url.dll" (i.e. Microsoft IE) you will be limited to 2,083 characters (including http://).

From where I sit you have two alternatives:

1. Build (or use) a TinyURL-style service
   that turns your long-urls into
   short, redirected ones. However even
   here you are going to run into the
   same URL length issue, just within
   the browser itself rather than your
   Runtime() statement. e.g. The browser window would open, go to the short-URL which would perform the redirect to the long-URL and fail.
2. Use a POST request and bury some or
   all of your URL parameters within
   it. Rather than using a GET call you
   can supply very long parameters
   within the body of an HTTP POST request. This
   would not be as simple as your example code. In fact this maybe quite tricky (or impossible) with the rundll32 url.dll combination (I am not familiar with it)...

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, I would suggest using the cross platform `Desktop.open()` or `Desktop.browse()` instead of Windows only `rundll32`. This will give you an IOException if it can't open the write application.

Answer (score 0):

It will also depend on the version of windows, because you may be exceeding the operating system's `MAX_PATH` length on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the Runtime.exec(String []) version, which you may have better luck with.  Just take all your space seperated arguments and pass them in as seperate strings:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String [] {"rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler", "urlarg1", "urlarg2"});`